# how to use conditional output filter for date field

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have a resource with TV "date". I want the content to be shown only if the field "date" is greater than the current time. I have a snippet called !curDate that returns unix timestamp. My code is:

```
[[*date:strtotime:ge=`[[!curDate]]`:then=`display:block;`]]
```

this example does not work, but this one works:

```
[[*date:strtotime:ge=`0`:then=`display:block;`]]
```

Is there any way to use output filters for date fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it should work as you have it, my only guess at that is that your curDate snippet is not returning a timestamp?

You could try to put all your logic in the curDate snippet and just pass the TV in...

[[!curDate? &date='[[*date]]']]

Do your date comparison in there and just return "display:block" [or whatever]

Comment: It's strange, but curDate snippet returns a valid timestamp. But your advice is was useful, thank you!